# AngularJS uibModal dependency not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem with injecting the `uibModal` dependency in my app.js:

`Angular Version:` 1.5.7
`ui.boostrap Version:` 1.3.3
`Bootstrap Version`: 3.3.6

I keep getting this error:

`angular.js:13708 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModal Provider <- $uibModal  <- ModalController`

**App.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls']);

app.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', '$uibModal ', function($scope, $uibModal) {
    $scope.showModal = function() {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: '../HTML/templates/login-modal.html',
            controller: 'newModalController',
            show: true
        });
    };
}]);

app.controller('newModalController', function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.close = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('close');
    };
});
```

**Index.html**:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.bootstrap/1.3.3/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.bootstrap/1.3.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../resources/js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="App">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="row" ng-controller="ModalController">
                    <img src="../resources/img/logos.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
                    <ul class="nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#" class="learn-more-link">Learn More</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="login-button-link" ng-click="showModal()">Take Action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Go to the modal [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) click on the **Edit in plunker** button, and you'll be able to see to code of a working example - Then compare the working example to yours and see what you're doing diffrent

Comment: @Alon Thank you for the advice. I looked it over the example carefully and I found the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need **ui-bootstrap-tpls** for modal.

Comment: great! it should work when you add it to angular.module

Comment: you can add it just like you add ui.bootstrap

Comment: Ok so here is what I added: `var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls']);` And the error still didn't go away :(

Comment: ui bootstrap recently added the 'uib' prefix to all of their components so try injecting modal using $modal instead of $uibModal

Comment: @Sam Now it gives the that same error except instead of uibModal is says modal...

Comment: it looks like there is extra space in '$uibModal  ' but it might be related with stackoverflow styles.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who needs help with this using the versions:

`Angular Version:` 1.5.7
`Angular Animate:` 1.5.7
`ui.boostrap-tpls Version:` 1.3.3
`Bootstrap Version:` 3.3.6

In your main `index.html` include the scripts. You only need `angular, angular-animate, ui.boot-tpls, and bootstrap`:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="../vendors/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="../vendors/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../resources/js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have two controllers doing the same thing .when you can simply have one but in this case it's not the problem just a bad design.

try rewriting your first controller so instead of this

`app.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', '$uibModal ', function($scope, $uibModal) {`

do this :

```
app.controller('ModalController', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
```

dont forget to remove the ']' at the end of the controller

hope this helps !

Comment: Hello thanks for the help! I managed to get it to work. In my index.html you do not need to include the ui.boostrap cdn only the ui.bootstrap.tpls. These are my imports `<script src="../vendors/js/angular.min.js"></script>`
        `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.js"></script>`
        `<script src="../vendors/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.min.js"></script>`
        `<script src="../resources/js/app.js"></script>`